# how could i merge two json in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

If I have two pieces of JSON, `[ { "a" : "b" , "c" : "d" } ,{ "a" : "e" , "c" : "f"} ]` and `{ "a" : "g" , "c" : "h"}`, is it possible to merge and obtain the following array in php?

```
[ { "a" : "b" , "c" : "d" } ,{ "a" : "e" , "c" : "f"} ,{ "a" : "g" , "c" : "h"} ]
```

Comment: Sure; convert to arrays, add the new value(s), and then encode back into JSON.

Comment: Absolutely. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Sure: `$value1[] = $value2;` (assuming you already parsed the JSON).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy for the moment, nothing.i really did'nt know how to deal with that problem.

Comment: @lipdjo Be sure to accept an answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $json1 = '[ { "a" : "b" , "c" : "d" }, { "a" : "e" , "c" : "f"} ]';
    $json2 = '{ "a" : "g" , "c" : "h"}';

    $json1 = json_decode($json1, true);
    $json2 = json_decode($json2, true);

    $final_array = array_merge($json1, $json2);

    // Finally encode the result back to JSON.
    $final_json = json_encode($final_array);
?>
```

Comment: Forgot to encode the merged array like the OP asked, but +1.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `json_encode()` should work , you can use `array_merge` on official PHP documentation `json_decode` on official PHP documentation

Answer (score -1):

You first need to decode the JSON objects:

```
$json1 = json_decode($data1, true);   
$json2 = json_decode($data2, true);
```

then merge the arrays:

```
$result = array_merge($json1,$json2);
```

and encode back to JSON:

```
$encodedResult = json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Huh? No. JSON is not an object you can merge in PHP. JSON is a serialization format.

Comment: They never said that. They said they had two pieces of JSON.

Comment: @Qix I have updated the answer. kindly remove the downvote :)